# Время выполнения программы

Tags: c++

Узнаю время работы так:

```
unsigned int start_time = clock();
metods();
unsigned int end_time = clock();
unsigned int search_time = end_time - start_time;
cout<<search_time;
```

Вопрос вот в чем, эти команды считают время в миллисекундах. Если ,например, функция метод будет сутки выполняться, то она будет считать так? Просто если переводить сутки в миллисекунды это очень большое число(может и больше работать).

Comment: Теперь посчитайте сколько миллисекунд может поместиться в unsigned int, переведите в человеческое время и не переживайте по этому поводу.

Comment: `4294967295 / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 = 49 суток`

Comment: Не забывайте еще, что clock() возвращает не миллисекунды, а тики, который еще надо делить на CLOCKS_PER_SEC. Плюс clock() измеряет процессорное время, которое может существенно отличаться от реального.

Comment: И еще уточнение, clock() возвращает не unsigned int, а clock_t. Что это за тип зависит от платформы и компилятора, у меня совпадает с uint64_t, например.

Comment: А как, тогда лучше время работы рассчитывать?

Comment: если есть доступ к STL и не нужны миллисекунды, можно использовать std::time.
   
`auto time_start  = std::time(nullptr); //получаем текущее время
 //выполняем код, который хотим замерить
 auto time_stop = std::time(nullptr); //получаем время окончания.`

В случае с clock_t можно так же использовать auto.